# Trying to parse json dictionary within list to create sqlite database

Tags: python, json, sqlite, dictionary, unicode

I have this code to write raw_input to file:

```
import json

a = raw_input("time meds taken?: format '@12:00' ")  
b = raw_input("had food at that point?: format '#0/1' ")

ax = {"meds": a}
bx = {"food": b}

with open("chance1.json", "a") as f:
   json.dump([ax, bx], f)

f.close()
```

I then end up with this:

```
[{"meds": "11:00"}, {"food": "0"}, {"meds": "12:45"}, {"food": "0"},   {"meds": "10:45"}, {"food": "0"}]
```

I then need to get the data from the above into a sqlite browser. I am currently using the following code:

```
import json
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect ('meds.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.executescript('''
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Meds;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Food;

CREATE TABLE Meds (
id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
time    TEXT UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE Food (
id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
meds_id  INTEGER,
status    TEXT UNIQUE
);

''')

fname = raw_input('Enter file name: ')
if ( len(fname) < 1 ) : fname = 'chance1.json'

str_data = open(fname).read()
json_data = json.loads(str_data)


for entry in json_data:
    time = entry["meds"]
    status = entry["food"]
    print time, status'
```

However, I end up with a traceback `KeyError: "food"`. Any advice how to go about solving this problem, please? Please note the code is not finished as I can't get beyond this part! (There's a chance the file is in Unicode too as when I print the entries I get a 'u' before each entry.)

Comment: try to print entry in you loop

Comment: When I print entry in the loop I get:
{u'meds':u'11:00'} etc for each entry

Answer (score 1):

Most of your post is unrelated to the `KeyError`. You are asking a dictionary for something that does not exist, namely a value associated with the key `'food'`.

One solution is to use `dict.get`, which returns None if the key cannot be found:

```
status = entry.get('food')
# status will be None if there is no 'food' key
```

You can also use `get` with a default value:

```
status = entry.get('food', 123)
```

Another possibility is that missing a key represents an error in your application. In which case, you need to consider why there is no `'food'` key.

Currently, you are storing the `'food'` and `'meds'` info in separate dictionaries, then combining them in a list. Maybe you want the following instead:

```
data = {"meds": a, "food": b}

with open("chance1.json", "a") as f:
   json.dump(data, f)
```

That puts the food and medicine info in the same dictionary. Note that opening the file with mode `'a'` means new data will be appended to the existing file. If you want to append to an existing list stored as json, you need to read the existing data, parse it, add the new item to the list, then re-write the file.
Inspect your json file, does it look like you expect?